# Javascript Regex Issue

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build a regex to test if the referrer contains a certain url (but includes query parameters etc)

Apologies if it's bad but it's my first attempt:

```
(ftp|http|https):\/\/urlhere\.com\/directoryhere(\?|/[^-+(a-zA-Z)]|$)
```

It works perfectly on here:
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

But when I try it in in JavaScript/Firebug using:

```
document.referrer.match(/(ftp|http|https):\/\/urlhere\.com\/directoryhere(\?|/[^-+(a-zA-Z)]|$)/gi);
```

I get the error:

`SyntaxError: unterminated parenthetical`

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `/` which is unescaped after directoryhere - (\?|**/**[

```
(ftp|http|https):\/\/urlhere\.com\/directoryhere(\?|\/[^-+(a-zA-Z)]|$)
```

Comment: Thanks, used your pattern with the below answer also.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed escape one `/` before `[^-+(a-zA-Z)]`

Try

```
document.referrer.match(/(ftp|http|https):\/\/urlhere\.com\/directoryhere(\?|\/[^-+(a-zA-Z)]|$)/gi);
```

Comment: That just returns null though? Should it not return false?

Comment: what does `document.referrer` returns in your case?